# Angular Form to MVC Entity Controller way to post data?

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am trying to pass data from angular form to c# entity controller in order to be stored to database. C# controller created by itself while using Entity Framework.  This is my angular code so far:

```
var formapp = angular.module("formapp", []);
formapp.controller("formctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.getFormData = function (animal) { 
        $scope.animalData = angular.copy(animal);
        console.log($scope.animal)
    };
});
```

and this is my C# controller(using entity):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "animalID,animalName,animalHabitat,animalClass")] Animal animal)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Animals.Add(animal);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(animal);
}
```

and also my html code:

```
<div ng-app="formapp" class="container" ng-controller="formctrl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Name</strong></label>
        <input name="name"
               id="name"
               type="text"
               maxlength="80"
               ng-model="animal.name"
               required
               placeholder={{name}}
               data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="habitat" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Habitat</strong></label>
        <input name="habitat"
               id="habitat"
               type="text"
               ng-model="animal.habitat"
               required
               data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="class" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Class</strong></label>
        <input name="class"
               id="class"
               type="text"
               ng-model="animal.class"
               required
               data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">
    </div>
```

Please tell me the way to pass the angular data into C# controller(I am very new to this).

Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: inject `$http` into the controller and call `post`: `$http.post('url', data);`

Comment: @Ric not any modify to C# controller?

Comment: Nope, you just need to pass data from angular to controller, controller doesn't need to change

Comment: Just adding to my comment, I meant the angular controller `formctrl`, not the c#

Comment: @Ric I will come back for further questions...! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, the documentation link that @AmitKumarGhosh provided has all the information required.

Comment: @Ric Entity generated 2 controllers with the same name...1) public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "animalID,animalName,animalHabitat,animalClass")] Animal animal) that makes the record and 2) public ActionResult Create() that returns the view. Having the following code, is not working: ` var animal = $scope.animal;
                var url = '/Home/Create';
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: animal,`

Comment: is one of those methods a post and the other a get? should work in that instance

Answer (score 0):

May be this complete code may help you

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SendDataStackOverFlow";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/AngularJs/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>SendDataStackOverFlow</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div ng-app="formapp" class="container" ng-controller="formctrl">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Name</strong></label>
            <input name="name"
                   id="name"
                   type="text"
                   maxlength="80"
                   ng-model="animal.name"
                   required
                   placeholder={{name}}
                   data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="habitat" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Habitat</strong></label>
            <input name="habitat"
                   id="habitat"
                   type="text"
                   ng-model="animal.habitat"
                   required
                   data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="class" class="col-md-3 text-align-right"><strong>Class</strong></label>
            <input name="class"
                   id="class"
                   type="text"
                   ng-model="animal.animalclass"
                   required
                   data-ng-change="getFormData(animal)">
        </div>
        <button ng-click="submitFormAngular()">Calculate</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('formapp', []);
    app.controller('formctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.name = 'MyName';
        $scope.submitFormAngular = function () {
            var animal = $scope.animal;

            //var data = { 'id': 10 };
            var url = '/AngularJs/SendDataStackOverFlow';
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: animal, //forms user object
                //  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
             });


        };

    });
</script>
```

and backend Controller

```
 public class Animal
        {
            public String name { get; set; }
            public String habitat { get; set; }
            //changed class to aninmalclass it is a reserved keyword
            public String animalclass { get; set; }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SendDataStackOverFlow(Animal animal)
        {
            return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
        }
```

Comment: I updated your code to: 

     `public JsonResult angulardata(Animal animal)
        {
            AnimalDBContext db = new AnimalDBContext();
            db.Animals.Add(animal);
            db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
        }`   
and unfortunately I get null values to the database. Can you please explain me the  foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" code?

Comment: Try too and baz is anonymous tyre...try converting to db entity and db.savechages()..and return Json{Success=true}; see the result file on .cshtml object.Success=true

Comment: lets say that I keep the DTO as it is ` [Key]
        public int animalID { get; set; }
        public string animalName { get; set; }
        public string animalHabitat { get; set; }
        public string animalClass { get; set; }`, still getting null values to the database

Comment: I have already set animalID as primary Key in database. Every async code is in comments, still nothing. Have you any other way to do it? Thank you very much

Comment: Even updating C# controller to         `public JsonResult AngularData([Bind(Include = "animalID,animalName,animalHabitat,animalClass")] Animal animal)
        {
            db.Animals.Add(animal);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
        }`  null values are stored to the database

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was quiet simple but I confused you because I didn't provide the DTO class. So, while I have animal.name, animal.habitat and animal.class in my html code, I have the following DTO:

```
 public class Animal

    {
    [Key]
    public int animalID { get; set; }
    public string animalName { get; set; }
    public string animalHabitat { get; set; }
    public string animalClass { get; set; }

}
```

So, I had to rename the values in html code. 
Quiet easy to fix, but extremely difficult to find(for me). Thank you all!